# break out of a subroutine

Tags: perl

what is the best way to break out of a subroutine & continue processing the rest of the script?

ie

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

&mySub;

print "we executed the sub partway through & continued w/ the rest 
of the script...yipee!\n";

sub mySub{

    print "entered sub\n";

    #### Options
    #exit; # will kill the script...we don't want to use exit
    #next; # perldoc says not to use this to breakout of a sub
    #last; # perldoc says not to use this to breakout of a sub
    #any other options????

    print "we should NOT see this\n";

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `return`?

Comment: i don't know...is that the way it's supposed to be done?

Comment: Oops, Anon. is not an abbreviation for Anonymous!

Comment: You should not use the special calling form `&mySub;` without good reason; a normal sub call should have () or not have &.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the expense of stating the obvious the best way of returning for a subroutine is ......

```
return
```

Unless there is some hidden subtlety in the question that isn't made clear

**Edit - maybe I see what you are getting at**

If you write a loop, then a valid way of getting out of the loop is to use `last`

```
    use strict ;
    use warnings ;
    while (<>) {
       last if /getout/ ;
       do_something() ;
    }
```

If you refactor this, you might end up with a using last to get out of the subroutine.

```
    use strict ;
    use warnings ;
    while (<>) {
       process_line() ;
       do_something() ;
    }

    sub process_line {
       last if /getout/ ;
       print "continuing \n" ;
    }
```

This means you are using `last` where you should be using `return`  and if you have wanings in place you get the error :

```
Exiting subroutine via last at ..... some file ...
```

Comment: Good point. And if you find yourself in the latter situation, the correct answer is to get `last` out of the sub: `last if do_something()` where do_something returns true when you need to "break out" and false otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Don't use exit to abort a subroutine if there's any chance that someone might want to trap whatever error happened. Use die instead, which can be trapped by an eval.